# How to find $f(x)$ in the following integral equation?

Tags: real-analysis, integral-equations

I have the following equation: $\int_{\alpha_0}^{\alpha_1} g(\alpha)f( g(\alpha) \cdot x) d\alpha = h(x)$

where $g(\alpha)$ and $h(x)$ are both given fucntions. Specifically, $g(\alpha)=cos(\theta - \alpha)$ where $\theta$ is a constant, and $h(x)$ is only known numerically.

How can I find $f(x)$ analytically or numerically?

---

**UPDATE 2 (analytical solution):**
The analytical solution can be obtained by transforming the equation into the generalized Abel's integral equation (see Wazwaz AM. (2011) Abel’s Integral Equation and Singular Integral Equations. In: Linear and Nonlinear Integral Equations. Springer, Berlin, Heidelberg) [[1](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-21449-3_7)].

For the sake of clarity, let's define $\Delta \equiv \theta-\alpha$:

$$\int_{\Delta_0}^{\Delta_1} cos(\Delta)f( x \cdot cos(\Delta) ) d\Delta = h(x)$$

It is worth pointing out now that in my problem, $\Delta \in (-\pi/2, \pi/2]$. In that case, due to the symmetry of the integrand, we can write

$$ 2 \int_{0}^{\pi/2} cos(\Delta)f( x \cdot cos(\Delta) ) d\Delta = h(x)$$

Let's now make the change $u \equiv x cos(\Delta)$, in which case $d\Delta = \frac{-1}{2x \sqrt{1-(u/x)^2}}du$ and

$$ \int_{u=0}^{u=x} \frac{u}{\sqrt{x^2-u^2}}f(u) du = xh(x)$$

If we call $\tilde{f}(u) = u f(u)$ and $\tilde{h}(u) = xh(x)$ the equation becomes

$$ \int_{u=0}^{u=x} \frac{ \tilde{f}(u)}{\sqrt{x^2-u^2}} du = \tilde{h}(x)$$

which is the generalized Abel's integral eqution with kernel $K(x,u)=(g(x)-g(u))^{-\nu}$ with $g(x)=x^2$ and $\nu=1/2$. The solution is obtained in [[1](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-21449-3_7)] and is given by

$$ \tilde{f}(u) = \frac{sin(\nu \pi)}{\pi} \frac{d}{du} \int_{0}^{u} \frac{g^{\prime}(t) \tilde{h}(t)}{ (g(u)-g(t))^{1-\nu} } dt$$

The conditions are that $0 < \nu < 1$ and that $g(x)$ is strictly monotonically growing and differencitable within some interval $0 < x < c$, with $g^{\prime}(x) \neq 0$ for every $x$ in the interval. This is the case singe $g(x)=x^2$ and $\nu = 1/2$.

---

**UPDATE (numerical solution):**
Following @Botond suggestion, we can do the following:

$$f(x) = \sum_n a_n x^n$$

and substituting in the integral equation

$$\sum_n a_n x^n \int_{\alpha_0}^{\alpha_1} g(\alpha)^{n+1} d\alpha = h(x)$$

Now we consider a set of points $x_j$ in which $h(x_j)$ is known, then we can write

$$\sum_n a_n x_j^n \int_{\alpha_0}^{\alpha_1} g(\alpha)^{n+1} d\alpha = h(x_j), \quad j=1,...,N$$

or, summing over repeated indices,

$$ x_j^n b_n a_n = h_j$$

The components of the vector $b$ are computed from $b_n =  \int_{\alpha_0}^{\alpha_1} g(\alpha)^{n+1} d\alpha$ (in order to solve the problem as a system of equations, we need to calculate the integral for at least $n=1,...,N$ where N is the number of interpolating points $x_j$).

If we define $C_{jn} = x_j^n b_n$, then the vector $A$ with $A_n = a_n$ can be obtained as

$$ A = C^{-1}H $$

where $H$ is the vector with the values $h_j$ (if the values of the integral for $b_n$ are $0$, some values of $C^{-1}$ will diverge, which might be problematic. In this case, since $g(\alpha)=cos(\theta-\alpha)$ we need to take care of the integration limits so that the integral does not vanish within that interval). Knowing the vector $A$ with the coefficients $a_n$, we can calculate the value of $f$ at any point $x$.

Comment: While h(x) is a constant it will be expressed in terms of $x$ since $x$ appears snide the integration. I think your equation is like: $$\int_{\alpha_0}^{\alpha_1} cos(\theta - \alpha)f( cos(\theta - \alpha)) \cdot x) d\alpha = h(x)$$ Do you know what h(x) is?

Comment: I got you, this is a tough one!

Comment: I know $h$ only numerically but not its exact functional depence on $x$, however, it's close to $h(x) = x^{k-1} exp(-x^k) $.

Comment: A suggestion for the numerical computation: Let's assume that $f$ is "nice" around $0$ (analytic, with big enough radius of convergence). Then it will have a series expansion:
$$f(x)=\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}a_n x^n$$
Which would mean that
$$g(\alpha)f(g(\alpha)x)=\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} a_n x^n g^{n+1}(\alpha)$$
And you can try to truncate it and calculate the coefficients with small enough $x$ values.

Comment: I expected that h(x) would have some information about $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $x\in\mathbb{R}$, let us do first a change variable:
    \begin{align*}
 \int_{\alpha_0}^{\alpha_1}g(\alpha)f(g(\alpha)x)d\alpha &\overset{u =g(\alpha)x}{=}  \int_{g(\alpha_0)x}^{g(\alpha_1)x}g\left(g^{-1}\left(\frac{u}{x}\right)\right)\frac{f(u)}{g'\left(g^{-1}(\frac{u}{x})x\right)}du \\
 &= \int_{g(\alpha_0)x}^{g(\alpha_1)x}\frac{u}{x}\frac{f(u)}{g'\left(g^{-1}(\frac{u}{x})x\right)}du \\
  &= \int_{g(\alpha_0)x}^{g(\alpha_1)x}\frac{u}{xg'\left(g^{-1}(\frac{u}{x})x\right)}f(u)du
 \end{align*}
    Let's name some variables to ease the notation : $A(x) = g(\alpha_0)x$, $B(x) = g(\alpha_2)x$ and $m(x,u) = \frac{u}{xg'\left(g^{-1}(\frac{u}{x})x\right)}$. 
    At this stage, we can use different numerical methods to find $f$.

I propose the following : $f$ can be approximated by a polynomial approximation, i.e. $f(u) = \sum_{i=0}^n a_i u^i$. Therefore, we have:
    \begin{align*}
  \sum_{i=0}^n a_i \underbrace{\int_{A(x)}^{B(x)}m(x,u)u^idu}_{I(x,i)} = h(x)
 \end{align*}
    As per the post above, we only know $h$ for a given set of $\{x_k\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$. Hence, the above equation can be written in a matrix-vector form:
    \begin{align*}
  \begin{pmatrix}
  I(x_0,0) & \dots & I(x_0,0) \\ 
  I(x_1,1) & \dots & I(x_1,1) \\ 
  \vdots & \dots & \vdots \\ 
  I(x_k,n) & \dots & I(x_k,n) & 
  \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
  a_0\\ 
  a_1\\ 
  \vdots\\ 
  a_n
  \end{pmatrix}
  =\begin{pmatrix}
  h(x_0)\\ 
  h(x_1)\\ 
  \vdots\\ 
  h(x_k)
  \end{pmatrix}
 \end{align*} 
Then by inverting the matrix, we can find the polynomial weights. Note that you have the choice on the numerical integration method to compute $I$.